# responsive nav menu doesn't show on top of animated banner

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

I looked for a similar issue and couldn't find it. I'm using bootstrap css3 html5, I have an animated banner on the home page done with Slider Revolution jQuery plugin. The navigation main menu appears behind the slider banner for tablets and mobile screens. I have tried with zindex values but is not working.

```
<style>
.mynavbar {
text-align:center;
z-index:1999 !important;
}
.mynavbar .nav {
float:none;
font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
font-size:30px;
font-weight:700;
color:#000;
}
.mynavbar .nav li {
display:inline-block;
float:none;
margin:0 15px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.mynavbar .nav li a {
color:#000;
}
.mynavbar .nav li a:hover {
color:#FC5504;
}
.mynavbar .nav li.mylogo a, .mynavbar .nav li.mylogo a:hover {
background:transparent;
max-width:200px;
}
.mynavbar .nav li.mylogo a img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
vertical-align:middle;
display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-brand {
display:none
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
.mynavbar {
text-align:left;
z-index:9999 !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
display:inline
}
.mynavbar .nav {
margin-top:3em;
}
.mynavbar .nav li {
display:block;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin:0;
padding-left: 2em;
border-bottom:1px solid #E9E6E6;
}
.mynavbar .nav li a {
border-radius:0;
display:block;
}
.mynavbar li.mylogo {
display:none
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="row-menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container"> 
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"     data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">    <img src="images/logo-small.png" width="125" height="104" alt=""/></a>     </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mynavbar" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">COMPAÑIA</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTOS</a></li>
                                    <li class="mylogo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/amapola-logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="recetas.html">RECETAS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">COMUNIDAD</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
            </div>
            <!-- /.container --> 
    </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

You can view the page here: [menu issue](http://amapolapr.com/Amapola-New/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting a z-index:100; on your .navbar worked for me.
it's on line 42 of bootstrap.min.css[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering me, but still is not working, what is strange is that in this page [link](http://amapolapr.com/Amapola-New/recetas.html) where is not a banner isn't working either and in this page [link](http://amapolapr.com/Amapola-New/receta-bacalaitos.html) it is working fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: hey Rigo Collazo, i may be wrong but i think you are putting the z-index on the wrong div.  try putting it on <nav class="navbar navbar-default">. not <div class="row-menu">

Comment: The thing is that I'm overwriting the default navbar because my menu has the logo in the middle. My css 'code' .mynavbar class has the z-index:1999;

Comment: sorry Rigo Collazo i may not be understanding you..."my menu has a logo in th middle" i'm not sure what that means.  anyways i added a screenshot to my answer showing you what i did (highlighted in blue) and the results (on the right).

Comment: rock on Rigo! good luck with the rest of you site. it's looking good so far.